# Can I use Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaLibrary for designtime data

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm

Does anybody know if its possible to use Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaLibrary for design time data?

I'm trying to pull random pictures from some design time data for a ViewModel using the  Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaLibrary.Pictures,  but I'm getting a System.ArgumentException when I try to access any of the MediaLibrary properties.  I had to attach the debugger from VS to Blend to see the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible. DesignTimeData should be on the machine used for development, while the MediaLibrary is only available on the phone/emulator.
For this to be able to work you'd have to have the design time code connect to the phone/emulator, request the images and have them returned. Becuase there is no way of doing this it's not posible.

You could, of course, get the sample files off the emulator and use them locally as design time data though.